# Autofac - dependency injection for MVC controller and Web Api controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac

I have MVC controllers (in Controllers folder) and Web Api controllers (in Api folder) in the same project: Here is the folder structure:

- Controllers

  - ProductController
- Api

  - ProductController

Here is my bootstrapper method:

```
        private static void SetAutofacContainer()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            //builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<DbFactory>().As<IDbFactory>().InstancePerRequest();

            // Repositories
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ProductRepository).Assembly)
                .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
                .AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();

            IContainer container = builder.Build();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        }
```

I can not inject repositories to my Web Api controllers. Here is the exception I get:

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type
>   'ProductController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless
>   public constructor.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When all else fails, read the documentation: http://docs.autofac.org/en/stable/integration/webapi.html#set-the-dependency-resolver

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You haven't set Web API's `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver`; you only set MVC's `DependencyResolver`.

Add the following line:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
    new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```