# How to do Dependency Injection with Autofac PropertiesAutowired() if the web application has both Mvc and WebApi controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a web application (1 project) with both **Mvc** and **WebApi** Controllers. I am trying to inject the dependencies with **Autofac** with **PropertiesAutoWired()**. My Mvc Controllers' properties are being injected, but the WebApi controllers' are not.

Here is my code:

**Global.asax:**

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        Logger.Logger.Initialize(Server.MapPath(string.Empty));

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(DependencyInjector.GetDependencyResolver(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
    }
```

**DependencyInjector:**

```
public static IDependencyResolver GetDependencyResolver(Assembly applicationAssembly)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterControllers(applicationAssembly).PropertiesAutowired(); //Mvc Controllers

        builder.RegisterApiControllers(applicationAssembly).PropertiesAutowired(); //Api Controllers

        DIContainer = RegisterServices(builder);



        return new AutofacDependencyResolver(DIContainer);
    }
```

**Registrations are done as follows:**

```
builder.RegisterType<Concrete>()
                .As<Abstraction>()
                .PropertiesAutowired()
                .EnableInterfaceInterceptors()
                .InterceptedBy(typeof(LogInterceptor))
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Every Controller has properties defined:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public ITestComponent TestComponent { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The dependency resolver for WebApi was not set. Please follow the link for the solution.

[Autofac - dependency injection for MVC controller and Web Api controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33018250/autofac-dependency-injection-for-mvc-controller-and-web-api-controller?rq=1)

Comment: If another post is exact duplicate - vote/flag/comment for duplicate instead of providing essentially duplicate answer. And definitely don't make self-answer out of that.